# Why weren't the Envoy's at Innenin backed up?

Tags: altered-carbon

Takeshi Kovacs lost his good friend Jimmy De Soto to a "viral strike" which resulted in the "real death" of many of the Envoy soldiers at Innenin. Why were these highly skilled, very valuable minds not backed up? The Envoy training was supposedly very costly and only a select few could make the cut.

Comment: The Envoy's were a tool used by the UN to enforce compliance from member worlds. They were meant to insure that the system wasn't broken.

Comment: Are you sure they weren't backed up? All we know is that they all were destroyed by infection, but the infection can also affect the backups.

Comment: How would the infection reach the back ups unless the soldiers were being backed up continually? With the known threat of a "viral strike" (Takeshi at one point calls out for a medic screaming "viral strike" during one of his flashbacks) backing up soldier while they are in combat would be a mistake. Any back ups would either be at the other end of a stellar range needle cast or on an "expanded format" disk aboard a local UN starship. The real death of his friends and fellow Envoy's means that either the UN allowed the back ups to become infected (highly doubtful) or they weren't backed up.

Comment: My recollection here is hazy, but weren't the envoys betrayed? If so, the traitor could point to all the backup locations (or disable/destroy the backups). You are right, there should be backups, but since the envoys were really destoryed, this means that the backups had to be destroyed as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right - they should be backed up. But something went wrong. Or rather someone.

In the "Altered Carbon" you can find this conversation between Kovacs and Bancroft:

> '[..]do you recall a General MacIntyre of Envoy Command, resident of Harlan's World, who was found gutted and decapitated in his private jet a year after the Innenin massacre?'
>
> 'Vaguely.' I sat, cold, remembering[...]
>
> 'Vaguely?' Bancroft raised an eyebrow. 'I'd have thought a veteran of Innenin could scarcely fail to recall the death of the commander who presided over the whole debacle, **the man many claim was actually guilty by the negligence of all those Real Deaths**.'
>
> 'MacIntyre was exonerated of all blame by the Protectorate Court of Inquiry,' I said quietly.

So it seems that while they Envoys should be protected from the Real Death by any means possible (including back-ups) they weren't, because someone messed up.